# Как деструктуризовать объект в массиве?

Tags: javascript, frontend, ecmascript-6

Есть объект:

```
var d = {
   a: [{b:5}, {b:7}]
}
```

Я хочу написать функцию, таким образом, что бы внутри сигнатуры она принимала этот объект `d`, и он бы там деструктуризовался таким образом, что внутрь функции пробрасывалось бы только значение `b` из первого элемента массива из свойства `a`.

Я придумал как додеструктурироваться до первого элемента массива

```
function dest({a:[arr]}) {
    console.log(arr)
}
dest(d)
```

А как можно додеструктурироваться, до свойства `b` этого элемента?

Т.е. сейчас эта функция выведет `{b: 5}`, a я хочу что бы в функцию попадало только `5` (т.е. значение свойства `b`, а не весь объект), подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли это как то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function dest({a:[{b: value}]}) {
    console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, чего то я тупанул

Comment: @vvtvvtvvt1 бывает. Рад, что помогло)